# Gitlab CI connection refused when running tests against server

Tags: gitlab-ci

I am trying to run tests against my server.
when i try running tests against my deployed server it works fine.

But what is run my server in a job and run tests some tests pass and for some i get client disconnected.
I also tried running my server as a service in the job but am getting connection refused.
Could someone help me out with this issue